# How to set latexmk to clean directory?

Tags: minted, latexmk

I know I can tweak `$clean_ext` setting inside `.latexmkrc` to clean specific files when invoking `latexmk -c`. However, it doesn't work for directory.

The directory I want to clean is `_minted-<main document name>`. I have tried `_minted-%R`, `./_minted-%R`, `./_minted-%R/*`. None of them work.

Comment: Do you have the output directory (`$out_dir`) set?

Comment: @JohnCollins No, I haven't. Everything are in default.

Comment: Actually there is a bug in `latexmk`.  It assumes that %R is the first item in the pattern you give in `$clean_ext`.  I'll need to correct that.

Comment: @JohnCollins any progress in fixing this? I also would like to see this.

Comment: I forgot to fix the bug.  It'll be fixed in v. 4.61, which is planned to be released today.

Comment: @JohnCollins Hi. I have `$clean_ext .= ' ' . '_minted-%R/* _minted-%R';` in my `latexmkrc`. However I need to run `latexmk -c` twice. The first time it removes the files inside the folder and only the second time it removes the folder itself. I also use `pythontex` and `$clean_ext .= " pythontex-files-%R/* pythontex-files-%R"` and I dont have the problems there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only currently available solution is to turn off caching in minted using `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}`.

@JohnCollins: `unlink_or_move` in latexmk.pl does not handle recursive directory removal as well.